# get error 401 when post request using XMLParsing swift library

Tags: swift, xml-parsing, codable, encodable

i'm testing XMLParsing library
(that use Codable protocol with XML request)

XMLParsing library link :
https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing

with https://openweathermap.org API

the API link is 
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"

my model is

```
struct weather:Codable {
    let q : String
    let appid : String
    let mode : String
}
```

and the request is

```
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let post2 = weather(q: "london", appid: "f4be702b940e5073d765cb2473f0b31b", mode: "xml")


        do{

            let body = try XMLEncoder().encode(post2, withRootKey: "current")

            request.httpBody = body

        } catch{}

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error))")// Handle error…
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {return }

            print("response: \(response)")
           print("data: \(data)")


    }
        task.resume()
```

I don't know where is the problem !
I always get error code 401

```
response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003bdedc0> { URL: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" =     (
        true
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" =     (
        "GET, POST"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        107
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 14 Jan 2019 07:14:16 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        openresty
    );
    "X-Cache-Key" =     (
        "/data/2.5/weather?"
    );
} })
data: 107 bytes
```

but on PostMan it working fine and get current data

[image]

Comment: Check parameter is correct or not and an API key ?

Comment: Your PostMan image shows that the parameters are embedded in url as query parameter, not in XML. Your Swift code is completely different that your PostMan request.

Comment: Thank you @OOPer
so I was send it in Header and it should be as Parameters

Comment: I meant Body not Header

Comment: Happy to see you could have solved your issue. By the way, (just my curiosity) why do you dare to use xml (which is not in fashion theses days and you need to use third party library to encode or decode) rather than json ? OpenWeatherMap's default output format is json.

Comment: @OOPer 
same thing I told to my company , but they told me you must use XML , That why I was just testing with OpenWeatherMap =(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @OOPer

I put it as Parameters on the link and change the request to GET
it working fine now

```
import UIKit
import XMLParsing


struct current:Codable {
    let city : City?
}

struct City:Codable {
    let id : String?

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=f4be702b940e5073d765cb2473f0b31b&mode=xml")!)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in



            do{

                guard (error == nil) else {
                    print("There is error")
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else {return}

                let newData = try XMLDecoder().decode(current.self, from: data)

                print((newData.city?.id)!)

            }catch let error {
                print("there is error",error)
            }

            }
               task.resume()


    }


}
```